# How to send a submitted email to an email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using a template in order to create a website. In the contact page I want to create a form where the user will be able to contact the company from a contact us template. The template comes with a contact_us.php file but I want to use only asp.net for the emails. 
    I am a beginner and I am not really sure how the controllers works in asp.net.

Heres my code:

View: **Contact.cshtml**

```html
@model Gsite.Models.ContactUs

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CustomLayout.cshtml";
}


<script src="~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form -->
    <!-- In order to set the email address and subject line for the contact form go to the bin/contact_me.php file. -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <h3>Send us a Message</h3>
            @if (ViewBag.Message == null)
            {
                <form method ="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label asp-for="Name">Full Name:</label>
                            <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Name"
                                  class="text-muted"></span>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label asp-for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label>
                            <input asp-for="phonenumber" type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <span asp-validation-for="phonenumber"
                                  class="text-muted"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label asp-for="Email">Email Address:</label>
                            <input asp-for="Email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Email"
                                  class="text-muted"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label asp-for="Message">Message:</label>
                            <textarea asp-for="Message" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Message"
                                  class="text-muted"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
                </form>
            }
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div>
        <div>
            @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
            {
                <div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/contact_me.js"></script>
```

Controller: **ContactController**

```
namespace Gsite.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Contact
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactUs vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailMessage msz = new MailMessage();
                    msz.From = new MailAddress(vm.Email);//Email which you are getting 
                                                         //from contact us page 
                    msz.To.Add("xxx@xxx.com");//Where mail will be sent 

                    msz.Body = vm.Message;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                    smtp.Port = 587;

                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                    ("xxxxx@xxxxx.com", "xxxxx");

                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                    smtp.Send(msz);

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for Contacting us ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = $" Sorry we are facing Problem here {ex.Message}";
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model: **ContactUs.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Gsite.Models
{

    public class ContactUs
    {

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int phonenumber { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong with your code?

Comment: when i am trying to send an email i have the error contact_me.php error 404, which means is trying to send the emails with the php file i have, so i supposed i am doing something wrong with the new method i am trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

This will work in an Asp.net MVC application. Does the application has got both Asp.net MVC and Php codes? Assuming 'yes', you need to set the `action` property of the form element.

e.g. `<form action="/Contact/Contact">`

Also set the "name" property of the input boxes to match the properties of the `ContactUs` object.

Comment: what the action property should be? Didnt get it

Comment: Action property of the html form element. e.g. `<form action="/Contact/Contact" method ="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>`

Comment: i have the following error "Server Error in '/' Application."